# jQuery mobile menu items get duplicated after clicking back button

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

Using jQuery Mobile the code below works, however when I click on a menu item then click 'back' all my menu items have duplicated/appended etc.

```
 $.each(siteData["pages"], function(i,v) {


        $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role=content]').append('' +
            '<a href="#' +  v["id"] +
            '" data-role="button">' + v["name"] +
            '</a>').trigger('create');



        var newPage = $("<div data-role='page' id='" + v["id"] +
            "'><div data-role=header><a data-iconpos='left' data-icon='back' href='#' data-role='button' " +
            "data-rel='back'>Back</a>" +
            "<h1>Dynamic Page</h1>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div data-role=content>Stuff here</div>" +
            "</div>");


        // Append the new page info pageContainer
        newPage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);



    });
```

How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make you a solution from your last question, it will be easier to understand

Take a look at  working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/3kPTf/

Basically before you add content you need to check if that constant already exist.

In your case each time you add a new button/page check if that button/page already exist like this:

```
if(!$('#second').length){
     // In this case this code block will execute if button with an id second don't exist
}
```

And here's a code example:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){  
    if(!$('#second').length){
        $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role=content]').append('<a href="#second" data-role="button">Second</a>').trigger('create');

        var newPage = $("<div data-role='page' id='second'><div data-role=header><a data-iconpos='left' data-icon='back' href='#' data-role='button' data-rel='back'>Back</a>" +
                        "<h1>Dynamic Page</h1>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div data-role=content>Stuff here</div>" +
                        "</div>");

        // Append the new page info pageContainer
        newPage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);        
    }
});
```

Comment: I did try this but it did not seem to work, here is what I tried....  $.each(siteData["pages"], function(i,v) {
if(!$(v["id"]).length){

Comment: You are forgetting to use a # tag each time you look for an id:  $.each(siteData["pages"], function(i,v) { if(!$('#'+v["id"]).length){